# Create header with merged cell and center aligned elements

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabularray

I would like to create a table as follows:

[image: expectation]

My current code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\label{tab:table_computational_time} 
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} { |
  l |
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X |
  c |
}
  \hline
  \textbf{wafer flow} & \textbf{MIP II model} & \textbf{MRT sequence}  \\
  \hline
  $[2]$  & 198 & 0.11 \\
  \hline
  $[3]$  & 204 & 0.11 \\
  \hline
  $[1,2]$  & 375 & 0.12\\
  \hline
  $[1,3]$  & 367 & 0.13\\
  \hline
  $[1,2,1]$  & 756 & 0.13\\
  \hline
  $[1,2,2]$  & 861 & 0.14\\
  \hline
  $[1,3,1]$  & 732 & 0.13\\
  \hline
  $[1,2,1,1]$  & 1288 & 0.13\\
  \hline
  $[1,3,1,1]$  & 1314 & 0.13\\
  \hline
  $[1,2,1,2]$  & 1538 & 0.15\\
  \hline
  $[1,2,2,1]$  & 1450 & 0.14\\
  \hline
  $[1,2,2,2]$  & 1444 & 0.14\\
  \hline
  $[1,3,2,1]$  & 1387 & 0.15\\
  \hline
  $[1,2,1,1,1]$  & 2381 & 0.13\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

However, the current result is as follows.

[image: current result]

Can anyone suggest on how to adjust the code in order to:

(a) merge the cell for "wafer flow" and add the "Computational time (seconds)" into the table title?

(b) have all numbers are aligned centered within each cell.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `tabularray` package. I think the code is self-explanatory:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}     % only for dummy text
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{table}[ht]\centering
\caption{One option}
\begin{tblr}
{
  colspec={cS[table-format=4]     % 4 integer digits
            S[table-format=1.2]}, % 1 integer and 2 decimal digits
  hlines,vlines,
  row{1,2}={font=\bfseries},
  cell{3-Z}{1}={preto={$[},appto={]$}}, % adding '$[' at the beginning and ']$' at the end of these cells
  cell{1}{2}={c=2}{}, % cell in row 1 and column 2 expands to 2 (c)olumns
  cell{1}{1}={r=2}{}  % cell in row 1 and column 1 expands to 2 (r)ows
}
wafer flow & {{{Computational time (seconds)}}}  \\
           & {{{MIP II model}}} & {{{MRT sequence}}}\\
2          &  198 & 0.11\\
3          &  204 & 0.11\\
1,2        &  375 & 0.12\\
1,3        &  367 & 0.13\\
1,2,1      &  756 & 0.13\\
1,2,2      &  861 & 0.14\\
1,3,1      &  732 & 0.13\\
1,2,1,1    & 1288 & 0.13\\
1,3,1,1    & 1314 & 0.13\\
1,2,1,2    & 1538 & 0.15\\
1,2,2,1    & 1450 & 0.14\\
1,2,2,2    & 1444 & 0.14\\
1,3,2,1    & 1387 & 0.15\\
1,2,1,1,1  & 2381 & 0.13
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{table}[ht]\centering
\caption{Another one}
\begin{tblr}
{
  colspec={cS[table-format=4]S[table-format=1.2]},
  row{1,2}={font=\bfseries},
  cell{3-Z}{1}={preto={$[},appto={]$}},
  cell{1}{2}={c=2}{},
  hline{1,Z}={0.8pt}, % first and last horizontal lines
  hline{3}={0.4pt},   % third horizontal line
}
wafer flow & {{{Computational time (seconds)}}}  \\
           & {{{MIP II model}}} & {{{MRT sequence}}}\\
2          &  198 & 0.11\\
3          &  204 & 0.11\\
1,2        &  375 & 0.12\\
1,3        &  367 & 0.13\\
1,2,1      &  756 & 0.13\\
1,2,2      &  861 & 0.14\\
1,3,1      &  732 & 0.13\\
1,2,1,1    & 1288 & 0.13\\
1,3,1,1    & 1314 & 0.13\\
1,2,1,2    & 1538 & 0.15\\
1,2,2,1    & 1450 & 0.14\\
1,2,2,2    & 1444 & 0.14\\
1,3,2,1    & 1387 & 0.15\\
1,2,1,1,1  & 2381 & 0.13
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elementary solution:

(a) for row merging, load the `multirow` package and use the  corresponding command.
(b) for alignment. change `l` to `c`, and `\raggedright` to `\flushright` in the `tabularx` preamble.

By the way,

- why use a `tabularx` where a basic `tabular` seems to be sufficient?
- Doing so, to avoid to type hundreds of `$`, uses  an `array` or load package `array` replace in the tabular preamble: `| l |` by `|>{$}l<{$}|` or  `|>{$}c<{$}|`

MWE combining all these ingredients :

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array,multirow,bigstrut}\begin{document}
% \label{tab:computational_time} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{|>{$}c<{$}}|}
% the construct *{3}{...} means repeat 3 times the format ...\hline
\multirow{2}[t 3]*{\textbf{wafer flow}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{computational time (s)}}\\
\cline{2-3}
& \textbf{MIP II model} & \textbf{MRT sequence}  \\
    \hline
    [2]  & 198 & 0.11 \\
    \hline
    [3]  & 204 & 0.11 \\
    \hline
    [1,2] & 375 & 0.12\\
    \hline
    [1,3] & 367 & 0.13\\
    \hline
    [1,3,1,1] & 1314 & 0.13\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center
\end{document}
```

Note: here, the `{center}` environment ensure centering in the current column. To get a numbered tabke with caption and label,insert it in a floating `{table}` (or `{table*}`,full page-width centering)
and replace the environment `{center}` by the `\centering` command inside the `table`. The (disabled) `\label` does make sense only in such a *numbered* environment.

**EDIT** The @juan answer is a less elementary but much more powerful solution. I use and recomnand it for complex designs, but perhaps not for the rather simple question from the OP.

Comment: Thank you, @Jhor. The code worked, however there was error message:  "unclosed $ found at close group }" and "unexpected close group } found after $" on the line: }{*{3}{|>{$}c<{$}}|}. In this case, what should I do? thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the reported error. With copy-paste the MWE, i don't get any error nor warning.   Did you load the three package in my MWE ? Is your LaTeX up-to-date ?